# Why am I losing margins with this Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap4 I have a multi-select and a seperate div showing what is currently selected as series of badges. (Because if using mobile device the select does not show what is currently selected, it only shows how many items are selected)

```
  <div class="form-control mb-2" id="fieldsCompleteness" name="fieldsCompleteness">                                
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">
      Acoustic
  </span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">
      Album
  </span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">
      Sort Album Artist
  </span>
  </div>
```

When users changes selection the badges have to be updated and this is done with a cal to this Javascript function.

```
function getSelectValues(select, readonlylist)
{                             
      var result = '';
    var options = select && select.options;
    var opt;

    for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++)
    {
        opt = options[i];
        if (opt.selected)
        {
            result+='<span class="badge badge-secondary">' + opt.text + '</span>';
        }
    }
    readonlylist.innerHTML =result;
    return result;
}
```

This works, except the margin between each badge disappears. I dont understand why as it seems I am just replacing existing Html ( a series of spans) with exactly the same. As I misunderstanding how innerHTML works does it have an effect on the classes defined on the outer div ?

Comment: If you generate the html without the linbreaks (like this `</span><span class="badge badge-secondary">`), do you still have the margins?

Comment: FWIW your initial HTML code has an unclosed `<span>` that theoretically might be affecting the display.

Comment: @LioraHaydont, thx that was it, have now added m1-1 class to the span anmd that works

Comment: @patstuart thx fixed question

Comment: Try using one of the `mx-*` classes. \* can be 1-5

Comment: @Klooven thats effectively what i dd, I used ml-1 (typo in comment above), if you want to create an answer to that effect I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

the spaces in the html (before the badge text) are rendered (and reduced to a single space) - you can achieve the same effect in your JS by adding the space, i.e. change

```
'<span class="badge badge-secondary">' + opt.text + '</span>'
```

to

```
'<span class="badge badge-secondary"> ' + opt.text + '</span>'
```

Comment: Thx, but better solution is to use css to create margin.

Comment: Sure, but then you need to change the style of your html

Answer (score 0):

```
  //works as answered above
    result+='<span class="badge badge-secondary"> ' + opt.text + '</span>';

    //but it is better without spaces between the + + unless you are concatinating different data types
    result+='<span class="badge badge-secondary"> '+opt.text+'</span>';

    //or you could just create and re-use a new variable like ...
    var x=' '; // or x='&nbsp;'
    //then use like...
    somestring+=somewordVAR+x;
    //so on so fourth
```

Comment: Thx, but better solution is to use css to create margin.